# Password Protecting A Webpage

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, html

Title may be a little misleading but I'll try to explain here.
Basically, when I put my website in 'offline mode' I have a section where admins can log in with a password. (They are **not** logging in with their accounts) The password is 'password' for this example. When a user types in the correct password, it should redirect them to the webpage, howvever it isn't, it's just echoing 'Incorrect password' - when it is in fact correct.

*The code is made up by me, as you can probably tell. I expected this not to work because I'm still in the very early stages of learning PHP*

HTML:

```
<div class="backdroplogin">
  <h2>Login to your account:</h2>
  <form action="/Offline" method="GET">
    <input type ="password" name="password_login" size="25" Value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</div>
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
//ADMIN LOGIN
$password = "AbCd0987connekt£*^%";

if (isset($_GET["password_login"])) {
   $password_login = $_GET["password_login"];

   if ($password_login == $password) {
   header("Location:/Admin/Panel");
 } else {
   echo "Incorrect password";
 }
 }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: First of all. 
NEVER THROW PASSWORDS AS GET PARAMS !!!! NEVER ! :)

Comment: ...not to mention as plain text, *groan*

Comment: As other means of protection I have an IP identifier. If a user accesses /Admin/Panel & doesn't have a listed IP they get redirected:

Comment: Then why you need such page ? 
Make a URL <a href...  and leave users to go directly there if they are not at your list redirect them to .. google :) .. 
By the way your problem are special chars because they get encoded when they are part of the url (GET params), this way inputed pass doesn't match your hardcoded.. if you replace it with POST it will be ok I think :)

Comment: Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. Don't mess with plain text passwords; it'll bite you in the "you know what" and bite you **hard**. ;-)

Comment: *By the way,* I tested your code and there's nothing wrong with it. Either you didn't enter the correct password when testing, or you're doing something else, or haven't updated your files on your server. Voted to close because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like Svetlio said.. It is a bad habit to send passwords using the get method. So instead use `method="post"` in your html form and `$_POST["password_login"]` in your php.

In your text you say you use `"password"` as the password for this tool, while in your php you check if the sent password is equal to `"AbCd0987connekt£*^%"`, so if you put in your password you should use `"AbCd0987connekt£*^%"`... or did you mean you use `"$password"`

Just another tip: for readability ability of your code try to indent :)

Answer (score 0):

You could verify that the password is correct and put a flag into a session variable. Then on the admin page do a check to see if that session flag is correct to access.

```
if($_SESSION['IsAdmin'] === true {
  //load/redirect to page
} else {
  die("You aren't an admin.");
}
```

Also, like others said - don't use GET for passwords, and definitely don't pass them as plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with comment. But just to answer your question:

Everything is working all right in your script, but I think you have a confusion when says "The password is 'password' for this example, instead the password is exactly: AbCd0987connekt£*^% as you wrote it in your code. I copied your code in my platform (changed action) and it's working as you want.